# Can't open database while using Django in VSCode

Tags: django, sqlite

I'm working on a Django project and I'm trying to open the database in VSCode but I keep getting a “failed to open database” error. The SQL explorer doesn't even show up on the explorer pane.

I have SQLite extension installed. I've also installed SQLite3 on my computer and it works according to the cmd prompt. But I'm still getting this error message.

I read the Django documentation and I'm not sure if I need to make any changes in `settings.py`. This is what it looks like

```
ENGINE: ‘django.db.backends.sqlite3’,
NAME: BASE_DIR / ‘db.sqlite3’,
```

I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: The default Django project creates a `.sqlite3` db within the project without any need of changing the settings. Do you want to see the data in the sqlite database by yourself or the `runserver` command throws an error?

Comment: The runserver command works very fine. Yes I want to see the data in the SQLite database.  I get the above errors when I right click “open database” from the SQLite3